# PHP SQL Pagination LIMIT clause

Tags: mysql, sql

i have problem in my sql query. my limit can not work properly.
the displaying error is this.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT0, 10' at line 137
my function is this in which i call query

```
function getprofitinstructornoman($id,$start,$per_page)
{
     $select="select s.id,s.name,s.phone,s.email from smaccount s where s.manager_id='".$id."'LIMIT".$start.", ".$per_page;
        $res = $GLOBALS ['mysqli1']->query ($select) or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli1']->error . __LINE__);
        if ($res->num_rows > 0)
        {return $res;}
        else{return false;}
}
```

please tell me where is the problem? and why my query is not working properly?
thanks
Mohsin

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a space. Use this instead of your line of code.

```
$select="select s.id,s.name,s.phone,s.email from smaccount s
where s.manager_id='".$id."' LIMIT ".$start.", ".$per_page;
```

I've added an extra space before and after "LIMIT".